# FindBugs Dead Store Warning - Should I restructure code or Ignore Warning

Tags: java, findbugs

I am getting a DeadStore warning with **Findbugs** on **int i** below.  I prefer not to write one-liners due to readability.  Is there a better way to write this so that there is not DeadStore to **i**, but as readable?

```
   if (aqForm.getId() != null) {
        try {
            int i = Integer.parseInt(aqForm.getId());
            aqForm.setId(aqForm.getId().trim());
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            result.rejectValue("id", "error.id", "Please enter an integer.");
            foundError = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to assign to `i`. You could just call `parseInt()` and ignore the result:

```
   if (aqForm.getId() != null) {
        try {
            Integer.parseInt(aqForm.getId()); // validate by trying to parse
            aqForm.setId(aqForm.getId().trim());
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            result.rejectValue("id", "error.id", "Please enter an integer.");
            foundError = true;
        }
    }
```

That said, I would create a helper function:

```
   public static boolean isValidInteger(String str) {
      ...
   }
```

and rewrite your snippet like so:

```
   String id = aqForm.getId();
   if (id != null) {
      if (isValidInteger(id)) {
         aqForm.setId(id.trim());
      } else {
         result.rejectValue("id", "error.id", "Please enter an integer.");
         foundError = true;
      }
   }
```

Comment: @EdgeCase: Not really. In fact, this is what I had at first, but then edited out. My reason was that the code I was showing wasn't functionally the same as your code (yours quietly accepts `null` whereas mine would complain about it).

Answer (score 5):

Just call the method and ignore the result, ideally with a comment to explain why:

```
// Just validate
Integer.parseInt(aqForm.getId());
```

It's not clear why you're trimming the version you *haven't* validated rather than the version you *have*, mind you. I'd prefer:

```
String id = aqForm.getId();
if (id != null) {
    try {
        id = id.trim();
        // Validate the ID
        Integer.parseInt(id);
        // Store the "known good" value, post-trimming
        aqForm.setId(id);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        result.rejectValue("id", "error.id", "Please enter an integer.");
        foundError = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I considered that, but Netbeans nags me about assigning the parseInt() to a variable.  I guess I'll ignore Netbeans instead of FindBugs.